# JSP Response Header not printing by EL or JSTL

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl, interceptor

I'm setting an argument in header i.e `response.setHeader("arg1", "test value");` from the interceptor. In the response page, I'm not able print it using EL or JSTL. But if I use scriptlet i.e `<%=response.getHeader("arg1")%>` then it prints the value.

I saw some example to use it like `${header['arg1']}` and `${response.header['arg1']}`. But its also not working.

Could you please help how to achieve it without scriptlet?

Comment: add your code here. I guess you are not importing JSTL library.

Comment: `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Welcome</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h3>${header}</h3>
 </body>
</html>`